# How can I join these three figures in a single document?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pdftex, circuitikz, scoping

**I have problems when using scope in circuitikz.**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%Inicio Preambulo
\ctikzset{%
monopoles/vcc/arrow={Triangle[width=0.8*\scaledwidth, length=\scaledwidth]},
monopoles/vee/arrow={Triangle[width=6pt, length=8pt]},
resistors/thickness=3,
}

%Fin Preambulo

\begin{document}

\ctikzsubcircuitdef{buffer}{in 1, out 1}{
    coordinate (#1-in 1) to[C,l=$C$,*-*] ++(2,0) coordinate(A)
    node[op amp, noinv input up, anchor=+, yscale=-1](OA){}
    (A) to[R,l=$R$,*-*]++(0,-2) node[ground](GND){}
    (OA.out) coordinate (#1-out 1)
    (OA.-)--++(0,1) -| (OA.out)
}

\ctikzsubcircuitdef{inver}{in 1, out 1}{
    coordinate (#1-in 1) to[R,l=$R_{1}$,*-*] ++(2,0) coordinate(B)
    node[op amp, anchor=-](OA){}
    (B) --++(0,1) to[R,l=$R_{2}$,*-*] ++(2.4,0) coordinate(C) 
    (C) -| (OA.out)
    (OA.out) coordinate (#1-out 1)
    (OA.+) --++(-0.3,0) --++(0,-0.4) node[ground](GND){} 
}

\ctikzsubcircuitactivate{buffer}
\ctikzsubcircuitactivate{inver}

\begin{circuitikz}\draw
    (0,0)\buffer{buf}{in 1}
    (4.38,0.49)\buffer{buff}{in 1}
    (8.76,0.98)\buffer{bufff}{in 1}
    (13.14, 1.47)\inver{inver}{in 1}
    (buf-out 1) -| (buff-in 1)
    (buff-out 1) -| (bufff-in 1)
    (buf-in 1) --++(0,3.5) coordinate(C)
    (C) -| (inver-out 1)
;\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}

\begin{document}
\ctikzset{diodes/scale=0.6}
\begin{circuitikz}\draw    
    node[op amp, noinv input up, yscale=-1](OA){}
    (OA.-) --++(0,1) coordinate(A) to[R,l=$R_{2}$,*-] ++(2.3,0) -| (OA.out) node[right]{$V_{o}$}
    (OA.+) --++(0,-1) coordinate(B) to[R,l=$R$,*-] ++(2.3,0) -| (OA.out)
    (A) to[C,l=$C$,*-*] ++(-2,0) node[ground](GND){}
    (B) to[R,l=$R$] ++(-2,0) node[ground](GND){}
    (A) --++(0,1) to[R,l=$R_{1}$,*-] ++(1.7,0) to[D, l=$D$, invert, fill=black] ++(0.5,0) -| (OA.out)
;\end{circuitikz}
\end{document} 

\begin{document}
%\ctikzset{diodes/scale=0.6}
\begin{circuitikz}\draw    
    node[op amp, noinv input up, yscale=-1](OAF){}
    (OAF.out) to[R, l=$R_{4}$,-*] ++(2,0) coordinate(A)
    (OAF.+) --++(0,-1.5) coordinate(B) to[R,l=$R_{2}$,*-] ++(2,0) -| (A)
    (-5,-1.99) node[op amp, noinv input up, yscale=-1](OAS){}
    (B) to[R,l=$R_{1}$] ++(-3,0) -| (OAS.out)
    (OAS.-) --++(0,1) coordinate(C) to[C,l=$C$] ++(2.3,0) -| (OAS.out)
    (OAS.+) --++(-0.5,0) node[ground](GND){}
    (-2,0.49) node[potentiometershape, rotate=-90,label=south:$R_{V3}$](P){}
    (P.wiper) -| (OAF.-)
    (P.east) node[vee](VEE){$V_{EE}$}
    (P.west) node[vcc](VCC){$V_{CC}$}
    
    (A) --++(0,3) coordinate (D) to[D, fill=black] ++(-3,0) to[R,l=$R_{5}$]++(-3,0) node[potentiometershape, rotate=-180, anchor=west,label=south east:$R_{V2}$](PP){} ++(-3,0)
    (PP.east) -| (C)
    (PP.west) --++(0.30,0) --++(0,-0.75) -| (PP.wiper)
    
    (D) --++(0,1.5) to[D, fill=black, invert] ++(-3,0) to[R,l=$R_{3}$]++(-3,0) node[potentiometershape, rotate=0, anchor=east,label=south east:$R_{V1}$](PPP){} ++(-3,0)
    (PPP.west) -| (C)
    (PPP.east) --++(0.30,0) --++(0,0.75) -| (PPP.wiper)
;\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not clear to me *how* do you want to join the three circuits...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,paperheight=17cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%Inicio Preambulo
\ctikzset{%
monopoles/vcc/arrow={Triangle[width=0.8*\scaledwidth, length=\scaledwidth]},
monopoles/vee/arrow={Triangle[width=6pt, length=8pt]},
resistors/thickness=3,
}

%Fin Preambulo

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\centering
\ctikzsubcircuitdef{buffer}{in 1, out 1}{
    coordinate (#1-in 1) to[C,l=$C$,*-*] ++(2,0) coordinate(A)
    node[op amp, noinv input up, anchor=+, yscale=-1](OA){}
    (A) to[R,l=$R$,*-*]++(0,-2) node[ground](GND){}
    (OA.out) coordinate (#1-out 1)
    (OA.-)--++(0,1) -| (OA.out)
}

\ctikzsubcircuitdef{inver}{in 1, out 1}{
    coordinate (#1-in 1) to[R,l=$R_{1}$,*-*] ++(2,0) coordinate(B)
    node[op amp, anchor=-](OA){}
    (B) --++(0,1) to[R,l=$R_{2}$,*-*] ++(2.4,0) coordinate(C) 
    (C) -| (OA.out)
    (OA.out) coordinate (#1-out 1)
    (OA.+) --++(-0.3,0) --++(0,-0.4) node[ground](GND){} 
}

\ctikzsubcircuitactivate{buffer}
\ctikzsubcircuitactivate{inver}

\begin{circuitikz}\draw
    (0,0)\buffer{buf}{in 1}
    (4.38,0.49)\buffer{buff}{in 1}
    (8.76,0.98)\buffer{bufff}{in 1}
    (13.14, 1.47)\inver{inver}{in 1}
    (buf-out 1) -| (buff-in 1)
    (buff-out 1) -| (bufff-in 1)
    (buf-in 1) --++(0,3.5) coordinate(C)
    (C) -| (inver-out 1)
;\end{circuitikz}

\ctikzset{diodes/scale=0.6}
\begin{circuitikz}\draw    
    node[op amp, noinv input up, yscale=-1](OA){}
    (OA.-) --++(0,1) coordinate(A) to[R,l=$R_{2}$,*-] ++(2.3,0) -| (OA.out) node[right]{$V_{o}$}
    (OA.+) --++(0,-1) coordinate(B) to[R,l=$R$,*-] ++(2.3,0) -| (OA.out)
    (A) to[C,l=$C$,*-*] ++(-2,0) node[ground](GND){}
    (B) to[R,l=$R$] ++(-2,0) node[ground](GND){}
    (A) --++(0,1) to[R,l=$R_{1}$,*-] ++(1.7,0) to[D, l=$D$, invert, fill=black] ++(0.5,0) -| (OA.out)
;\end{circuitikz}
%\ctikzset{diodes/scale=0.6}
\begin{circuitikz}\draw    
    node[op amp, noinv input up, yscale=-1](OAF){}
    (OAF.out) to[R, l=$R_{4}$,-*] ++(2,0) coordinate(A)
    (OAF.+) --++(0,-1.5) coordinate(B) to[R,l=$R_{2}$,*-] ++(2,0) -| (A)
    (-5,-1.99) node[op amp, noinv input up, yscale=-1](OAS){}
    (B) to[R,l=$R_{1}$] ++(-3,0) -| (OAS.out)
    (OAS.-) --++(0,1) coordinate(C) to[C,l=$C$] ++(2.3,0) -| (OAS.out)
    (OAS.+) --++(-0.5,0) node[ground](GND){}
    (-2,0.49) node[potentiometershape, rotate=-90,label=south:$R_{V3}$](P){}
    (P.wiper) -| (OAF.-)
    (P.east) node[vee](VEE){$V_{EE}$}
    (P.west) node[vcc](VCC){$V_{CC}$}
    
    (A) --++(0,3) coordinate (D) to[D, fill=black] ++(-3,0) to[R,l=$R_{5}$]++(-3,0) node[potentiometershape, rotate=-180, anchor=west,label=south east:$R_{V2}$](PP){} ++(-3,0)
    (PP.east) -| (C)
    (PP.west) --++(0.30,0) --++(0,-0.75) -| (PP.wiper)
    
    (D) --++(0,1.5) to[D, fill=black, invert] ++(-3,0) to[R,l=$R_{3}$]++(-3,0) node[potentiometershape, rotate=0, anchor=east,label=south east:$R_{V1}$](PPP){} ++(-3,0)
    (PPP.west) -| (C)
    (PPP.east) --++(0.30,0) --++(0,0.75) -| (PPP.wiper)
;\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```